# Problem updating android contact picture with ContentResolver.Update()

Tags: java, android

I am new to android. My requirement is to update contact picture with the selected one. Below is the code I am writing to implement this

```
byte[] imageBytes = imgContactPhoto.getDrawable().toString().getBytes();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactId);
    values.put(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1);
    values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, imageBytes);
    values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(contactId));
    cr.update(uri, values, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " = " + contactId, null);
```

imgContactPhoto is the ImageView, in the first line, I am extracting Bytes array of the image set upon it and updating the contact (with cotact id = contacted). 
When I debug the code, it passes all the above statements smoothly without any exception, but the contact picture is not updated.When I check the values of uri and values during debug in new watch, 
"uri"             uri cannot be resolved to a variable
"values"        values cannot be resolved to a variable

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1 correction (with cotact id = contactID(Integer Value))

Comment: Hello I found tutorial on setting up contact photo. Just follow link : http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/30/handling-contact-photos-all-api-levels/

Answer (score 3):

The short ansewer is you are trying to update Contacts.CONTENT_URI, but the photo is stored on Data.CONTENT_URI.

Do you only ever need to update the primary photo of the contact? If so it is fairly straight forward. To obtain the id of the Data entry use the PHOTO_ID on Contacts as this will automatically be referencing the Photo which is has a IS_SUPER_PRIMARY equal to 1. Once you have this id don't add RAW_CONTACT_ID into the ContentValues and change your update statement to:

```
Uri dataUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Data.CONTENT_URI, dataId);
cr.update(dataUri , values, null, null);
```

If you maybe setting a photo on a contact that does not have one already it gets a bit trickier. Because you need to insert the ContactsContract.Data entry you need to figure the correct ContactsContract.RawContact to attach the Data entry too. If there is just one it is simple, but if the user has a couple of sync sources there maybe several RawContacts for the Contact. In which case you will need to decide which one to attach to.